# OAuth2 - Can a trusted Client access User resources with Client Credentials flow

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, clientcredential

Looking at this explanation of the client credentials grant type from the OAuth website:

> The Client Credentials grant type is used by clients to obtain an access token outside of the context of a user.
>
> This is typically used by clients to access resources about themselves **rather than to access a user's resources.**

In case the client is a trusted app (internally developed), is it ok for it to access users' resources?

Technically, the app isn't the "resource owner" of these resources, but because it's a "super" app, developed internally, it should be able to access them, for the sake of implementing the organization's business requirements.

For example - think of your user in Google. The Google maps app creates resources owned by you (e.g places you "saved" on the map). Then, some Google daemon app with "super" permissions, can access those resources you created, in order to process them and show you relevant ads.

Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s a fairly typically scenario in my opinion.

There are a few additional best practices to consider for your trusted client like storing secrets in a key vault, rotating the secret on a schedule, limiting and logging administrator access, etc.

Comment: Thanks Scott, yeah that all makes sense.

Comment: Quick follow up question - How would the resource server know that it's ok to serve this resource X that is owned by someone else? I was thinking a dedicated OAuth scope or a set of scopes would do the job. Would that work?

Comment: I definitely prefer to use separate endpoints and scopes to separate trusted (application) from untrusted (user) scenarios. I’ve seen them combined and it creates a lot of extra complexity, and therefore risk of getting it wrong.